# Expected value and function of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables, expectation

If X,Y are two random variables such that for every integrable increasing function $f$
$$E(f(X))\leq E (f(Y))$$
can I say that $X\leq Y$ almost surely?

Comment: No. As a counterexample, suppose $X$ has support on $[0, 1]$ and define $Y$ to be $1 - X$. Then, for every function $f$, $E[f(X)] = E[f(Y)]$, but $X(\omega) = 1 - Y(\omega)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two independent random variables with 0-1 distribution: $X$ with $P(X=0)=1-s$ and $P(X=1)=s$, $Y$ with $P(Y=0)=1-t$ and $P(Y=1)=t$. A condition in question translates to $(t-s)\bigl(f(1)-f(0)\bigr)\ge 0$ which is equivalent to $s\le t$. What about $P(X\le Y$)?